# Is it possible to deploy a React Native app to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, react-native

Is was wondering if its possible to deploy a React Native app to Heroku? The reason I ask is because then I can retrieve the url and place it in an iframe to mimic an iPhone where the user can then tryout the app without actually having to install it on to the iPhone via iTunes.

Comment: Check out https://appetize.io/ . I have a few React Native apps there and it works great.

Answer (score 12):

This is possible using [react-native-web](http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/overview-getting-started--page) ([sources](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)).
There are few things that you have to do to set this up on heroku:

- in the settings tab of your your heroku app dashboard
  set the buildpack as `heroku/nodejs`,
- in `package.json` set the `build` script to build your web version from RN sources, for example, if you are using expo: `expo build:web`,
- create a Procfile in the root directory to serve the web
  version: for example, if you used expo, the build directory is `web-build` and therfore the command should be `npx serve web-build`,

Additionally, if you use expo, make sure to add the `expo-cli` as a dev dependency: `npm install -D expo-cli`.

You will then simply need to push to heroku the usual way. By default, heroku will run `yarn build` (or `npm run build` depending on wether you used one or the other to generate your lock file).

In the end, here is what the `package.json` file might look like (using expo again):

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "build": "expo build:web"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.6",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.6.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "expo-cli": "^4.0.16",
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "jest-expo": "~40.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And the `Procfile` simply consists of a single line:

```
web: npx serve web-build
```

You could probably achieve similar results using [reactxp](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/) instead of reac-native-web, but I never tried it myself.

### Client side routing

#### Configuring Heroku for client side routing

If you use client side routing (react navigation for example), you will have to setup a few more things to make sure linking works. With the previous build alone, client side routing will fail (404 errors) because heroku will try to route requests on its own, but your app needs everything to end up at `index.html` so it can perform routing tasks on its own (client side routing).

We will thus **prevent any Heroku routing** by adding a second buildpack [heroku-community/static](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static) next to `heroku/nodejs`. This second buildpack is configured via a `/static.json` file ([default values](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#web-server)):

```sh
{
  "root": "web-build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

#### Configuring webpack for client side routing

You probably already have this part setup because otherwise you would have 404 errors even locally. To allow client side routing it seems like we also need to configure webpack (`output.publicPath` and `devServer.historyApiFallback`), [with expo](https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-webpack/) this can be done by running `expo customize:web` and then editing `/webpack.config.js` with:

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
    config.output.publicPath = '/';
    config.devServer = {
        ...config.devServer,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    };
    return config;
};
```

There is a nice article about these routing issues you might have here: [Fixing the 'cannot GET /URL'](https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/)

Answer (score 2):

Steps for deploying React native/expo app to heroku:

1:
set heroku buildpack as static: >heroku buildpacks:set heroku-community/static

2:
Add static.json for static buildtype:
{
"root": "web-build/",
"routes": {
"/**": "index.html"
}
}
More settings here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#configuration

3:
npm run build (package.json: "build": "expo build:web") --> Creates web-build folder

git add .

git commit

git push heroku master

heroku open